# Conditional mutual information notations

Tags: math, probability, probability-theory, probability-distribution

It might be a naive question but I am really struggling with this. I have looked at number of papers and articles that present the formula of the Mutual information and the Conditional Mutual information.. they usually write it in two ways :

1. [first formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ur1Jv.png)

and

2. [second formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XHgJ.png)

Are those formulas actually equivalent ? and does `PX(x)` actually means the same as `P(x)` ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about probability and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PX(x)` is indeed the same as `P(x)`. Both of them represent the probability `P(X=x)`. These two formulas are equivalent. You can move from the second to the first by using the following law: `P(A,B)/P(B)=P(A|B)`. Then applying this law on the second formula we get

```
p(x,y|z)/[p(x|z)p(y|z)]=[p(x,y,z)/p(z)]/[{p(x,z)/p(z)}*{p(y,z)/p(z)}]=
=[p(x,y,z)*p(z)]/[p(x,z)*p(y,z)]
```

The last transition follows from the cancellation of one of the `p(z)`. And the result gives you the first formula.